# Why are both these Shebang lines compatible?

Tags: python

new to coding and python.

I'm using the flask framework to write an app, and the tutorial asks that I should include a shebang line to invoke the virtual environment, when I run the file:

run.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python

from app_folder import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

However, on my `__init__.py` file there is a different shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app_folder import views
```

When I run the `run.py` file it doesn't seem to matter that the two shebangs are different - why is that? I assumed they would have to be the same as I thought that being different they would be invoking different versions of the program.

Comment: Note that the `#!flask/bin/python` shebang constrains you to have a sub-directory of the current directory call `flask` which has a `bin` directory in it that contains a `python` executable.  Normally, you make it so that scripts can be run with any directory as the current directory by using an absolute pathname in the shebang line: `#!/home/you/flask/bin/python` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second shebang is simply ignored. Only the shebang line of the file named on the command line is used to locate the executable to pass the file to.

The shell hands the file to `flask/bin/python`. To Python, shebang lines are *just comments*.

The shebang line in the `__init__.py` file will probably not work; you cannot run a module inside a package and hope to still use the rest of the package as such; a script is always run as `__main__` unless you use the `-m` switch (in which case you probably want a `__main__.py` file in your package anyway).

Comment: in fact, you probably _don't want_ a shebang line in files that are part of a module hierarchy — those should only be run with `python -m` (if at all), or funny things happen to your imports.

Comment: @Eevee: indeed, elaborated on that a bit.